# .net Bitmap changes color of image

Tags: .net, image, crop

I am trying to resize the image without the loss of any color. But I can't get this to work. See the picture below, the top one is the original, the bottom one is the one which has gone through .NET.

**My question is, how can I keep the colors?**

I have tried a lot of different settings, looking for GDI+ bugs. Changing the Palette, changing the ImageAttributes to TileFlipXY which people suggest on the internet. But none seems to work.

[image]

My Code:

```
Public Class ImageEditor
    Private _img As Image
    Private _format As Imaging.ImageFormat
    Private _pixelformat As Imaging.PixelFormat
    Private _palette As Imaging.ColorPalette

    Public Sub New(ByVal img As Image)
        _img = img
        _palette = _img.Palette
        _format = _img.RawFormat
        _pixelformat = _img.PixelFormat
    End Sub

    Function getImage() As Image
        Return _img
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Een stuk afbeelding uit een afbeelding knippen
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="x1">Start X positie</param>
    ''' <param name="y1">Start Y positie</param>
    ''' <param name="width">Breedte van het stuk dat geknipt wordt</param>
    ''' <param name="height">Hoogte van het stuk dat geknipt wordt</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub crop(ByVal x1 As Integer, ByVal y1 As Integer, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer)
        ' Cropping the image
        Dim tmp As New Bitmap(width, height, _pixelformat)
        tmp.SetResolution(_img.HorizontalResolution, _img.VerticalResolution)

        Dim imageAttributes As New Imaging.ImageAttributes
        imageAttributes.SetWrapMode(Drawing2D.WrapMode.TileFlipXY)
        Using g = Graphics.FromImage(tmp)
            g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            g.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
            g.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
            g.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy

            g.DrawImage(_img, New Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), x1, y1, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageattributes)
        End Using
        _img = tmp
    End Sub

End Class
```

My converter class.. Any my .NET code:

```
        ' Load file
        Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(filename)
        Dim format As Imaging.ImageFormat = img.RawFormat

        ' Crop and scale
        Dim editor As New ImageEditor(img)
        editor.crop(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
        img.Dispose()
        ' Generate binairies
        Dim newImg As Image = editor.getImage()

        Dim myEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality
        Dim myEncoderParameters As New EncoderParameters(1)
        Dim myEncoderParameter As New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100&)
        myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter

        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
        newImg.Save(ms, GetEncoder(format), myEncoderParameters)
        Dim binairies As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
```

Comment: Did you tried just review original image from _img without any transformation?

Comment: The original image without going through the ImageEditor does have the right color. When I create a new bitmap, the color is wrong.

Comment: I have discovered that when in Photoshop I uncheck the srgb button it is the same as .NET produces. So it's something to do with SRGB.

Comment: When I disable the ICC profile in photoshop. And then save, .NET can handle it OK. But .NET should be able to use another ICC profile.

Comment: Use Image.FromFile(filename, true)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as Hans Passant says. I just had to add the true at `Image.FromFile(filename, True)`

This true stands for:

> Creates an Image from the specified file using embedded color management information in that file.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx